# How to design a Design a 64 x 8 memory using two 16 x 4 RAM chip?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, flipflop

Can someone suggest how I would start this project?  I want to design a Design a 32 x 4 memory using two 16 x 4 RAM chip.

Comment: Designing circuits is not what is done here. Question will be closed.

Comment: Your title totally mismatches your question

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your title and question do not match. I assume your question is 'how to design a 32k x 4 memory using two 16k x 4 RAM chips?'.

This can be done as shown below.
[image]

14 address lines access the 16k nibbles from each ram chip. The 15th address line is given as chip select. When A14 is low, the lower bank is selected and when it is high, the upper bank is selected.

Comment: It's 32 not 32k

Comment: OK.In that case each RAM requires 4 address lines (A0-A3) and the highest bit A4 should be given as chip select.